# Is it possible to pass type parameter information through to a dagger subcomponent?

Tags: generics, kotlin, dagger, subcomponent

I'd like to be able to expose type information to a subcomponent inside a generic abstract class. We have an `abstract class` with a type parameter that is set in a subclass (the latter of which is bound in our graph), and try to pass this type information to a subcomponent inside this class. The way attempted tries to attach a type parameter to the subcomponent.

Here is a more fleshed-out example of what I'd like to achieve:

```kotlin
interface Runner<T> {
    fun run(t: T)
}

data class Data<T>(
    val options: T
)

abstract class AbstractRunner<Options> : Runner<Data<Options>> {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mySubcomponentBuilder: MySubcomponent.Builder<Options>

    // Constructing this relies on dynamicData which must be generated at runtime
    // (hence the subcomponent)
    // @Inject
    // lateinit var subRunner: Runner<Options>

    override fun run(data: Data<Options>) {

        // Some dynamically generated data - we can't use assisted injection as this is injected into other classes in
        // the subgraph.
        val dynamicData = Random.nextInt()

        mySubcomponentBuilder
            .dynamicData(dynamicData)
            .build()
            .subcomponentRunner()
            .run(data.options)
    }
}

// We have other objects with associated Runner implementations;
// we list one for brevity.
object Foo
class MyRunner @Inject constructor() : AbstractRunner<Foo>()
class SubRunner @Inject constructor(s: String) : Runner<Foo> {
    override fun run(t: Foo) {}
}

@Component(modules=[MyModule::class])
interface MyComponent {
    fun runner(): Runner<Data<Foo>>
}

@Module(subcomponents=[MySubcomponent::class])
interface MyModule {
    @Binds
    fun bindMyRunner(runner: MyRunner): Runner<Data<Foo>>
}

// This does not work due to generics being banned on (Sub)Components.
@Subcomponent(modules=[SubModule::class])
interface MySubcomponent<T> {
    // We can't parameterise the method; generics are banned on methods in (Sub)Components.
    fun subcomponentRunner(): Runner<T>

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder<U> {
        @BindsInstance
        fun dynamicData(i: Int): Builder<U>
        fun build(): MySubcomponent<U>
    }
}

@Module
object SubModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideString(i: Int) = i.toString()
    @Provides
    fun provideSubRunner(s: String): Runner<Foo> = SubRunner(s)
}
```

Of course, this does not take:

```
error: @Subcomponent.Builder types must not have any generic types
```

Is it possible to wire through this information some other way? If the variable bound in our subcomponent were not needed, we could just bind our `subRunner: Runner<Options>` in our main graph without issue, as commented.

Comment: Just add a `fun subcomponentRunner()` for each concrete type you want. You're going to provide different implementation for each value of `T` anyway

Comment: While i am going to provide a different value for each type, having to add a different subcomponent method for each one is incredibly tedious and will require having to switch on the type of `data.options` to ensure the correct method is called.